# Problemas com .clone() para radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radiobutton, clone

Estou fazendo um botão "adicionar" que á cada clique adiciona uma `div com Radio` buttons abaixo da própria div. Eu to com problema em clicar no radios que quando clico em de alguma linha adicionada e clico em outro de outra linha ele apaga o valor clicado de antes e só deixa o valor clicado no momento.

este é o meu código:

```
   $("#adiciona-fone").click(function () {
     // altero o valor div // 
    var divDuplica = $("#duplica").clone();
    divDuplica.attr('id', 'duplica_'+contador);

    //altero o valor do id hidden //
    divDuplica.children(":input").attr('id','id-telefone_'+contador);

    // altero o valor do id da div que tem todos os radios
    divDuplica.children("#tipo-fone-pessoa").attr('id','tipo-fone-pessoa_'+contador);
    var divTipoFone = divDuplica.children("#tipo-fone-pessoa_"+contador);
    var inputDivTipoFone = divTipoFone.children('.radio').attr('id', 'radio_'+contador);

    // boto a div no fim da div.
    $("#duplica").after(divDuplica);
    contador++
    return false;
});
```

Este é o meu html :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons "interagem entre si" através do name.

Quando você clona uma linha com radio buttons você está de fato adicionando novas opções aos radio buttons da linha anterior.

Sugiro que você crie uma inteligência para adicionar novas linhas sem utilizar o clone, de maneira que você use um name diferente.

Ou então use os mesmos métodos que você utilizou para dar um id único só que para o atributo name.

Comment: Exato. O que eu devo mudar é o atributo name dos radios. Obrigado.